# How to get with custom-columns resource limits and requests of all containers in namespace in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I tried this:

```
k get po -n myns -o=custom-columns=NAME:.spec.containers.name,MEMREQ:.spec.containers.resources.requests.memory,MEMLIM:.spec.containers.resources.limits.memory,CPUREQ:.spec.containers.resources.requests.cpu,CPULIM:.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu
```

but it returned me this:

```
    NAME     MEMREQ   MEMLIM   CPUREQ   CPULIM
    <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>
    <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>
    <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>
    <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>
    <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>
    <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>
    <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>   <none>
```

Comment: This question might be better suited for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [SF].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `containers` is a list, so you would have to either supply the index or `*` for all containers.

Here is an example from my environment, you can tweak your rest of the command.

```
kubectl get po -o=custom-columns=NAME:.spec.containers[*].name
NAME
nginx
nginx



kubectl get po -o=custom-columns=NAME:.spec.containers.name
NAME
<none>
<none>
```

To visualize the structure, here is an example with one pod, notice that a list is returned in the output of this command:

```
kubectl get pod my-nginx-66b6c48dd5-gq6vd  -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers}'
[{"image":"nginx:1.14.2","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","name":"nginx","ports":[{"containerPort":80,"protocol":"TCP"}],"resources":{},"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File","volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount","name":"default-token-cbmr2","readOnly":true}]}]
```